# Make a Div with relative position go under the footer div when scrolling

Tags: css, html, position, overlay

i'm really not very familiar with CSS and HTMl so take it easy with me
I'm editing a purchased template, and i'm running into a little problem, you can check how it looks right here and understand my problem: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10843829/SITE%20INFORBYTE/shortcodes-text.html

The problem is:
I've got the sidebar div, and i **made it to move along with the page with the "position:fixed"** attribute on it's div...
The thing is, now **it scrolls over the footer div**.
I tried to follow this: http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/ but it didn't work out really well.

Now some code for deeper understandment of my problem.

**Source Code**

```
<div class="grid_4 sidebar " style="position:fixed" id="sidebar">
```

---

**sidebar widget container - CSS**

```
    .sidebar h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    color:#333333;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff}

.sidebar .widget-container h3 {
    margin-left:40px}

.footer .widget-container h3 {
    font-size:15px;}

.footer .widget-container {
    color:#848484}

.footer .widget-container a {
    color:#fff}

.sidebar ul, .sidebar ol {
    margin:0;
    padding:0}

.sidebar ul li {
    list-style:none}

.sidebar_space {
    padding:10px }

.sidebar .box,
.sidebar .widget {
    margin-bottom:20px}

.sidebar .widget-container {
    font-size:13px;
    padding:20px;
    margin-bottom:30px;}

.sidebar .box .widget-container {
    padding:0}

.sidebar .widget-container ul {
    margin:0;}

.sidebar .widget-container ul li ul{
    margin:0 0 0 5px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your footer to `position: relative;` and give it a `z-index: 5000;` like so:

```
.footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

Comment: Hey Nathanael, thank you!
I was going crazy into the CSS making the z-index:5000; and it wouldn't work. Why? Because the position was not set to relative.

Answer (score 1):

Set the z-index of the footer to something obscene, like:

```
z-index: 3000;
```

That should force it to stay on top. Alternatively, you can try playing with negative values of the sidebar, and that could work too.

Comment: To anyone this isn't working for, add `position:relative;` as well.